# How to bring the JfreeChart in jsp?

Tags: java, jfreechart

How to use the Jfree Chart in java web application.I have created the image at the server side and I need to show image In the JSP.I don't need to store the image in local system.

Comment: make a url that creates the image and outputs the response then just call that url to get the image in your html

Answer (score 0):

You can create an image using jfreechart and then give the path of that image in your JSP where you want to show the chart.

Try this :

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <%@ page  import="java.awt.*" %>
    <%@ page  import="java.io.*" %>
    <%@ page  import="org.jfree.chart.*" %>
    <%@ page  import="org.jfree.chart.entity.*" %>
    <%@ page  import ="org.jfree.data.general.*"%>
    <%
      final DefaultPieDataset data = new DefaultPieDataset();
      data.setValue("One", new Double(43.2));
      data.setValue("Two", new Double(10.0));
      data.setValue("Three", new Double(27.5));
      data.setValue("Four", new Double(17.5));
      data.setValue("Five", new Double(11.0));
      data.setValue("Six", new Double(19.4));

      JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart ("Pie Chart ", data, true, true, false);

     try {
         final ChartRenderingInfo info = new ChartRenderingInfo(new StandardEntityCollection());
         final File file1 = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath(".") + "/piechart.png");
         ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(file1, chart, 600, 400, info);
         } catch (Exception e) {
            out.println(e);
         }
     %>
    <html>
      <body>
         <img src="piechart.png" WIDTH="600" HEIGHT="400" BORDER="0">
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I don't  want use scriplet here.

Comment: I need to use through output stream